# Space after <?php ?> causing problem. Why?

Tags: php, debugging, blob

After a several hours looking for this bug, I was socked and a bit upset to realize it was due to a espace character after `?>` tag in my php script.

## The problem

I was simply trying to show a file that was storage in a BLOB table in a database using PHP. After investigating and isolating the problem, it seemed to be around these lines of code bellow.

**problem.php**

```
<?php
  require_once('empty-script.php');
  $data = file_get_contents('./images/download.jpeg');
  header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
  echo $data;
?>
```

**empty-script.php**

```
<?php
?>
```

## The Bug

Instead of getting an output, this was the outcome on the browser. Not desired.

[image]

## Getting Nuts

At some point I decided to comment the `require_once`. After noticing the bug was gone, I was about to blame it for the issue. Then it occurred me to create another empty file and import it.

The new empty file was working, `require_once` not necessarily was the one to be blamed.
After a few minutes I noticed that there was an extra space after `?>` in `empty-script.php` that was causing the image/file to not be rendered.

## The Question

Is that a bug from PHP? Am I unaware of a documentation regarding this? Why this happens?

This is my server configuration

[image]

Comment: Any text jumbled prior binary file content (JPEG) makes it invalid.

Comment: New lines at the end of `empty-script.php` don't seem to make it invalid.

Comment: ***One*** new line gets chucked away, yes.